# How to import a fortran dll in C#, whose subroutine contains array output?

Tags: c#, fortran

fortran part

```
subroutine Add(C,A,B)
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT::Add
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES STDCALL,ALIAS:'Add'::Add
    !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES REFERENCE::C
    
    implicit none
        real*8 :: A(4),B
        real*8 :: C(4)
        integer :: i
        C=0.0
        do i=1,4
            C(i)=A(i)+B
        enddo
```

C# part

```
[DllImport("testdll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void Add(ref double[] c,double[] a, double b);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double[] a = new double[]{1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0};
    double b = 4.0;
    double[] c=new double[4];
    Add(ref c,a,b);
    Console.WriteLine(c);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Assume this is my fortran code,how should I use this dll in C#?
Where A,B are my Inputs,and C is my Output.
When I run C# program, it returns none.
Almost all of the questions on internet didn't mention this case.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: By doing some P/Invoke I guess?

Comment: [The first](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1099942/FORTRAN-Interoperability-with-NET-Exchanging-Compl) [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+import+a+fortran+dll+in+C%23%2C+whose+subroutine+contains+array+output).

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't mention how to deal with array outputs

Comment: I'm new to C#, so the P/invoke is kind of hard for me actually I didn't know it

Comment: Referer to simple types chapter, it's a simple [out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier) parameter modifier there. Don't be afraid to try.

Comment: Sinatr, I've read that page, but it still didn't solve my problem. It whould be greatly appreciated if  you could help me to see where am I wrong with the program

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all guys,I've solved this problem.
And this is my test program, hope it can help others.

Fortran part:

```
subroutine Add(C,A,n)
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT::Add
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS:'Add'::Add


implicit none
    integer :: n
    real*8 :: A(n)
    real*8 :: C(n)
    integer :: i
    do i=1,n
        call plusone(A(i),C(i))
    enddo

    end

    subroutine plusone(a,b)
    implicit none
    real*8 a,b
    b=a+1.0
    end
```

C# part

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace cstest
{
    public static class FortranMethod
    {
        [DllImport("testdll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern void Add(double[] c,double[] a,ref int n);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = 4;
            double[] a = {1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0};
            double[] c=new double[n];
            Add(c,a,ref n);
            for (int i = 0; i < c.Length;i++ )
            {
                Console.WriteLine(c[i]);
            }   
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```